# "Flickering Issue with Canvas Animation on Mobile Devices"

Tags: animation, requestanimationframe

I've attempted to optimize the canvas animation for mobile devices by using requestAnimationFrame to ensure smooth updates. Additionally, I've implemented event listeners for scroll and window resize events to adapt to changes in the viewport.